# Python File Path Name

Tags: python, file, io

What is the difference between `"./file_name"`, `"../file_name"` and `"file_name"`when used as the file path in Python?

For example, if you want to save in the file_path, is it correct that `"../file_name"` will save `file_name` inside the current directory? And `"./file_name"` will save it to the desktop? It's really confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`./file_name` and `file_name` mean the same thing - a file called `file_name` in the current working directory.

`../file_name` means a file called `file_name` in the in the parent directory of the current working directory.

**Summary**

`.` represents current directory whereas `..` represents parent directory.

**Explanation by example**

if the current working directory is `this/that/folder` then:

- `.` results in `this/that/folder`
- `..` results in `this/that`
- `../..` results in `this`
- `.././../other` results in `this/other`

Comment: What do you mean by parent directory of the current working directory?

Comment: What if my current directory is the Desktop?

Comment: I think I got it. My Desktop folder is located in my asus folder which is why files are being saved there. Am I correct?

Comment: Usually, your current working directory is the directory in which you ran the python file. To find out your current working directory during execution do this `import os` and `print(os.cwd())`

Comment: I have another question. what does `'.'` mean? It was being used for the `log_dir` arg in the `tf.train.write_graph()` function

Comment: You mean the `.` as in the dot operator or `.` as in the current directory used in file paths?

Comment: like this `tf.train.write_graph(session.graph_def, '.', '../actitracker_har.pbtxt')`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `./` is the current directory, while `../` is the parent of the current directory. Both are actually hard links in filesystems, i.e., they are needed in order to specify relative paths.

Let's consider the following:

```
/root/
    directory_a
        directory_a_a
            file_name
        directory_a_b
        file_name
    directory_b
        directory_b_a
        directory_b_b
```

and let's consider your current working directory is `/root/directory_a/directory_a_a`. Then, from this directory if you refer to `./file_name` you are referring to `/root/directory_a/directory_a_a/file_name`. On the other hand, if you refer to `../file_name` you are referring to `/root/directory_a/file_name`.

In the end, `./` and `../` depend upon your current working directory. If you want to be very specific you should use an absolute path.